# PhpStorm select text in terminal

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

I recently changed work and moved from VSCode to PhpStorm.

Is there some way I can use `ctrl` + `shift` + arrows to select text while using Terminal in PhpStorm?

It's very convenient to do this in VSCode when I need to execute multiple similar commands - I can just select and delete big chunks and replace them with new input. Now I have to delete each character individually by holding `delete`.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Selection with mouse works fine in PhpStorm's terminal (PhpStorm 2021.1.4, Windows 10, standard `cmd.exe` as a shell).

Comment: @LazyOne it onlu highlights texts - highlighting with mouse doesn't allow to delete that block of text. Also I want keyboard solution not mouse solution

Comment: 1) It allows you to select and then copy that block (or can auto-copy if appropriate option is selected in the Settings). So if you have some long command and need to repeat it but without some part in the middle then the approach (with copying) would be to do the above 2x times. Sure, it may not be that convenient as select last command and then just select and delete that part with one press (as compared to holding `'Del` for a bit.

Comment: 2) My experiments did not reveal the "keyboard only" solution for your case. You can check the Issue Tracker to see if there is a similar ticket there (my quick search did not brought any close matches): [LINK](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23{Tools.+Terminal}+select+text) 3) IDE settings, Keymap -- it does not seem to have any specific actions for text selection in the terminal (except "Select All"): https://i.imgur.com/S2MtkYD.png